# URL check resume method in java

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I wrote this method for check URL.

```
public boolean checkresume(String URL) throws IOException{
    HttpURLConnection urlc;
    urlc = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+1+"-");
    urlc.getResponseCode();
    Log.e("Check Resume",urlc.getHeaderField("Accept-Ranges").toString());
    if((urlc.getHeaderField("Accept-Ranges").equals("bytes"))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

this method have not bug when import a URL with ability to continue URL, return be "true".

But when import a URL without ability to continue URL, crashed app and return this log

example for url : https://codeload.github.com/libuchao/Dictionary/zip/master

log:

```
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466): Process: com.yyxu.download, PID: 8466
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadService@429f1b38 with Intent { act=com.yyxu.download.services.IDownloadService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2877)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:161)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadTask.checkresume(DownloadTask.java:92)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadTask.<init>(DownloadTask.java:76)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadManager.newDownloadTask(DownloadManager.java:517)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadManager.newDownloadTask(DownloadManager.java:342)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadManager.addTask(DownloadManager.java:86)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadService.onStart(DownloadService.java:58)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2860)
08-01 13:25:12.201: E/AndroidRuntime(8466):     ... 10 more
```

problem is `com.yyxu.download.services.DownloadTask.checkresume(DownloadTask.java:92)`

line 92 is : `Log.e("Check Resume",urlc.getHeaderField("Accept-Ranges").toString());`

please help me.

I am sorry for my speak English.

Thanks.

Comment: it means that or urlc is null or getHeaderField return null so toString fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getHeaderField(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) returns the value of the named
 header field, or `null` if there is no such field in the header. This method returns `String` so no need to use `toString()`.

It simply means your `URLConnection` don't have Header field named `Accept-Ranges`. Make sure your are using the exact name of header as it's case sensitive.
You can also use method of `HttpURLConnection` to get header from number [`getHeaderField(int n)`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28int%29) returns `nth` header. But more than that you should do `null` check before using it to avoid `NPE` like this:

```
if(urlc.getHeaderField("Accept-Ranges") != null) {
    // ... Move ahead
```